# Separating a string that has no whitespaces in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I am having problems with separating string characters.
These are the raw strings that I have

```
"MH 02:30pm-04:00pm TF 08:30am-10:00am"
"MTWS 07:00 am-09:00 am, A 08:30 am-11:00 am"
"WS 01:00pm-05:00pm F 11:30am-01:00pm"
```

These strings are database values from a table column named "schedule". I only have read 
privileges so I can't alter data, and the database is huge making it difficult to change 
the format of the schedule column.

My purpose is to extract the class schedule from the string returning the day(MTWHFSA), 
start time and end time. What I have done so far is use StringTokenizer. I have not been 
successful since as you can see, the string that the database returns varies in format. 
It doesn't always return the same format. So I've thought to remove all whitespaces so 
that all will have the same format. Example:

```
"MH02:30pm-04:00pmTF08:30am-10:00am"
```

Please, can anyone help me with how to extract the day(MTWHFSA), start time and end time
from the string above?

Here's the sample code:

```
String sched = "MTWHFS 02:30pm-04:00am W 08:30am-10:00am";
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(sched,",");
    while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
        StringTokenizer anotherToken = new StringTokenizer(token.nextToken(),"\\ ?\\-?");
        while(anotherToken.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(anotherToken.nextToken());
        }
    }
```

This outputs correctly:

```
MTWHFS
02:30pm
04:00am
W
08:30am
10:00am
```

But if the string is like this:

```
String sched = "MTWHFS 02:30 pm-04:00 am W 08:30 am-10:00 am";
```

It's output becomes:

```
MTWHFS
02:30
pm
04:00
am
W
08:30
am
10:00
am
```

The output varies when the string format is different, that's why I removed the whitespaces so that the string format will be the same.

But when the string has no white spaces like this:

```
String sched = "MTWHFS02:30pm-04:00amW08:30am-10:00am";
```

It outputs this which is no what I wanted.

```
MTWHFS02:30pm
04:00amW08:30am
10:00am
```

Can anyone help me with this so that this string:

```
String sched = "MTWHFS02:30pm-04:00amW08:30am-10:00am";
```

will output:

```
MTWHFS
02:30pm
04:00am
W
08:30am
10:00am
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is (MTWHFSA) in your current strings btw??

Comment: `.replaceAll("\\s","")` will remove all spaces , if you need to remove even the separators then you need to write a regex !

Comment: You can remove the spaces and find all the `:` and read from two chars before to four chars after.

Comment: You could do with a data model refactoring. This is a really poor way of storing such data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way:

```
String regex = "(?<=am|pm),?-?|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.replaceAll(" ", "").split(regex)));
```

For `"MTWHFS 02:30 pm-04:00 am W 08:30 am-10:00 am"` it prints:

```
[MTWHFS, 02:30pm, 04:00am, W, 08:30am, 10:00am]
```

**Explanation:**

It may be a bit difficult to understand if you haven't played around with `split` and probably regular expression a bit already.

Firstly, remove all spaces with `replaceAll`.

Then it's on to the [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

`(?<=am|pm)` checks that the previous characters are either `am` or `pm`, then you also include an optional `,` and `-` so these are consumed in the split.

Alternatively, the previous character must be between A and Z (`(?<=[A-Z])`) and the next character must be between 0 and 9 (`(?=[0-9])`).

**Example:**

```
MH02:30pm-04:00pm
  ^ here the previous character is "H" and the next character is "0",
     thus it fulfils the second condition, it splits on a string of length 0

MH02:30pm-04:00pm
         ^ here the previous characters are "pm",
            thus it fulfils the first condition, it splits on the "-"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions. The benefit of using a regex would be that it also checks for you whether the input has the expected format.

This regex should match a single schedule entry :

```
([A-Z]+)([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:am|pm))-([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:am|pm))
```

The [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the regex give you the day, start and end times. You can use it in Java like this:

```
// the input string which may contain spaces
String s = "MH02:30pm-04:00pmTF08:30am-10:00am"; 
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); //remove the spaces
Pattern rg = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+)([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:am|pm))-([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:am|pm))");
final Matcher matcher = rg.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()) {
    //find all the groups
    for(int i=0;i<=matcher.groupCount();i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one. Thank you so much!! Great help!! :)